# How to get higher and lower values for a given data type?

Tags: firebird

In Delphi I often use the [`Low`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Low.html) and [`High`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_High.html) functions which returns respectively the highest and the lowest value for a given ordinal data type.

Is there something similar in Firebird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no feature in Firebird to get the minimum or maximum value of a type.